# How to return the number of a month in C# function

Tags: c#

I want to return the number of a month and i made a function but it always returns 0

this is my code:

```
public int getNrMonth(String s)
    {
        int nr=0;
        if (s.Equals("January"))
            nr = 1
        if (s.Equals("February"))
            nr = 2;
        return nr;


    }
```

Could someone tell me wath is wrong please? I'm beginner!

Comment: Are you trying to compare "january" with "January"?

Comment: It's not an answer to your problem but you should take a look at  
DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames which return a string array of the Month for the current culture. Then you can use the index to get your month number from your month name :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Why wouldn't you use the built in function:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month
```

Here is an example on use:

[How to parse a month name (string) to an integer for comparison in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c)

Comment: I think you're confused? `Month.toInt` is not a built-in function. The OP in the question you link to was asking if there's anything *like* that; the actual accepted answer suggests using `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: There is no `Month.toInt` operation. You're looking for the `DateTime.Month` property.

Comment: Typing at too many things sorry for the confusion.  I have edited to be correct.

Comment: Uh ? There's no such method !

Answer (score 5):

It'd be better to do it like this:

```
switch (s.Trim().ToUpper())
{
    case "JANUARY": return 1;
    case "FEBRUARY": return 2;
    // etc.
}

return 0;
```

Reasons:

1. `switch` is optimized to begin with (small point, but worth mentioning).
2. Once you have the value, all the remaining `if` checks are pointless.
3. Assuming you want "january" and "January" and "   January " and "jaNuarY" all to return 1, the `Trim()` and `ToUpper()` calls will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you're a beginner, but you still have tools at your disposal. Set a breakpoint and step through in the debugger. Take a look at the value of `s` and `nr` as you do. Notice which `if` statements execute the `nr =` part and which you don't. Then you will understand. As it stands I don't think you pasted your real code in, because your question is missing a semi colon and might not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
     string value = "June";
     DateTime result;
     bool ok;
     ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MMMM",
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
     if ( ok )
     {
        int monthNumber = result.Month;
        Console.WriteLine(monthNumber);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do it the simple, easy way when you can do it the long, complicated LINQ way!

```
    int GetMonthNumber(string month)
    {
        return System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames
            .Select((m, i) => new { Month = m, Number = i + 1 })
            .First(m => m.Month.ToLower() == month.ToLower())
            .Number;
    }
```