# How do I get the number of days in a particular month and year?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the days for particular month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360953/how-to-get-the-days-for-particular-month-and-year)

Given the following method:

```
GetDaysPerMonth(string monthName, string year);
```

And the values "1" and "2010", how can I return the number of days within the specified month?

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: @Chris: you may have read between the lines :P

Comment: Why have you asked this question twice?

Answer (score 7):

How about using [DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx)?

```
System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)
```

As an aside though, and possibly opening myself up to be shouted at, couldn't you just have tried typing "get days in month" into Google?

Comment: +1 for the google comment. http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=get+number+of+days+in+month+c%23&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=get+number+of+days+in+month+c%23&gs_rfai=&fp=b8ea99853242201d the search gives your specified api as 5th result (in msdn).

Comment: The OP didn't specify the calander system they're using, so Tim's answer is better.

Comment: @Skizz - yes. There is an implicit assumption in mine that user wants the days in the month for the currently set calendar, which may not actually be true.

Answer (score 6):

[`Calendar.GetDaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/681s2taz.aspx)

Note that the `Calendar` class accepts month numbers, not month names, because month names are vary in different languages.

Answer (score 2):

You simply want the [`System.DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) static method.

Example:

```
var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2010, 7) // = 31
```

If you're given the year and month as strings, just call `int.Parse` to get the value as a number.

Comment: @anishmarokey: Don't be dense. Give the OP more credit than that.

Comment: @Anish: i need to get output like mm/dd : 1/1,1/2,1/3,1/4