# How do I convert month names to int?

Tags: string, datetime, .net-3.5

I have a column called Month in a stored proc which returns to me the month in string name terms (eg. January, Febuary, March etc.)

I would like to convert that to an integer.

Is that possible without just using a number of select case statements?

I would like to do this in .NET 3.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c/258828#258828

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a month name (string) to an integer for comparison in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTime.Parse and then get the Month property of the date:

```
string monthName = "January";
DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0} 1, 2000", monthName)).Month
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server do this `SELECT DATEPART(month, GETDATE())`

Also a duplicate of this question [How to parse a month name (string) to an integer for comparison in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I came through this issue recently (on Client Side using Javascript) and after a few searches on the internet, I decided to do it myself. Though I did it using Javascript, still I'll give u a .net solution as well.
The Javascript first:

```
function convertToIntMonth(monText) {
//Your arrays for the valid months for which you can throw exception (I did not do it) if the parameter is out of these 12.
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var monInt;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
//in this loop, we'll check for the match in parameter and array items.
            if (monText == monthNames[i])
            { 
//If match is found, we'll return the +1 value of actual match (as month array's index goes from 0 to 11, and we require it from 1 to 12)
monInt=i+1}
        }
        return monInt;
    }
```

Now the .NET (C#): Did not tested yet, still I hope you could find the logic

```
public int convertToIntMonth(string monText) {
        string[] monthNames = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
        string monInt=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (monText == monthNames[i])
            { monInt=i+1}
        }
        return monInt;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could store Name->Number mappings in an array (look through the array until you find the one you want) or a hash (lookup the month name in the hash to get a number -- benefits from supporting any number of languages and abbreviations, too). I'd rather store the information in data structures than in code, but that might just be my own irrational behavior.

**EDIT**

In response to @roboshop's "Sounds like a lot of work", perhaps it is compared to one-liners that the platform supports, but if your customers ask you to support abbreviations such as "Jan", "Fe", "Mar", I think using a data structure gives a lot of additional flexibility:

```
months = { "ja" => 1, "jan" => 1, "january" => 1,
           "fe" => 2, "feb" => 2, "february" => 2,
           "ma" => 3, "mar" => 3, "march" => 3,
           "ap" => 4, "apr" => 4, "april" => 4,
           "my" => 5, "may" => 5,
           "jn" => 6, "jun" => 6, "june" => 6,
           "jl" => 7, "jul" => 7, "july" => 7,
           "au" => 8, "aug" => 8, "august" => 8,
           "se" => 9, "sep" => 9, "sept" => 9, "september" => 9,
           "oc" => 10, "oct" => 10, "october" => 10,
           "no" => 11, "nov" => 11, "november" => 11,
           "de" => 12, "dec" => 12, "december" => 12,
           "januar" => 1,
           "februar" => 2,
           "märz" => 3,
           "mai" => 5,
           "juni" => 6,
           "oktober" => 10,
           "dezember" => 12}

puts "Month %s is %d" % [ARGV[0], months[ARGV[0].downcase]]
```

Of course, now you have to know the localized versions of months your users want, but it is far easier to support requested abbreviations.