# How to display month number on selecting month name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of Months displayed in a drop down. On selecting a particular month I would like to display the number of the month in a text box.

For example if I select `January` I would like to display it as `01`, likewise for the others.

This is the sample code I have written:

```
string monthName = "january";
int i = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Use this code to convert the selected Month Name into a Month Number**

```
DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month
```

**Need String Padding?**

```
PadleftMonthNumberString.PadLeft(2, "0")
```

**References**

- [How to parse a month name (string) to an integer for comparison in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c)
- [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)
- [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

**Sample Console Application**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mnthname = "january";
            int i = DateTime.ParseExact(mnthname, "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will not get the date right i will get only month names from Dropdown as per your answer i would like to give a proper date time

Comment: the word "time" does not exist in your question. I do not follow. You can ignore the fact that DateTime is used in my answer. That is simply the class that owns the ParseExact function.

Comment: So what should i take then instead of DateTime

Comment: Use my answer exactly and you will be fine. It solves your question exactly as asked, so I think you will have no problem.

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` i am getting this error. I passed string as `January`

Comment: You're declaring "mnthname" but you're using "monthName". Can you fix that and see if it works?

Comment: Please see my Update. I pasted your code in EXACTLY and it works perfectly in a new console application. Please verify which line your error is coming from

Comment: Could the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` be different for Vivekh and that's causing the issue?

Comment: Good Idea -- @Vivekh, please update your code to use `InvariantCulture` -- see my updated examples; however, I still think your error is somewhere else.

Comment: I would like to get `01` instead of `1`

Comment: Vivekh, please read my whole answer. Use `Mystring.PadLeft(2, "0")`

Answer (score 3):

Just trying to improvise(?) on hamlin11's answer, you can bypass the parse code by using the dropdown's selectedindex+1

Comment: Agreed, assuming chronological ordering and the existence of all 12 months

Comment: I think this can be made as a statement instead of answer

Comment: that's my bad, i didn't have commenting privilege at that time

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative that doesn't require any parsing or using the index of the drop down.

Create a list of month value to month text and then use this to create a dictionary to map the text to the value. Like this:

```
var months =
    from m in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    select new
    {
        Value = m,
        Text = (new DateTime(2011, m, 1)).ToString("MMMM"),
    };

var list = months.Select(m => m.Text).ToArray();
var map = months.ToDictionary(m => m.Text, m => m.Value);
```

Now the drop down can be populated from `list` and any value selected can be converted back to the value using `map`.

```
var month = map["January"];
```

This generates the text rather than parsing it so it should work for any culture.

Answer (score 0):

Using the index of the drop down list is a good option. You can also bind a dictionary to a drop down list. Creating a dictionary containing month names for the current culture:

```
var months = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Select ((m, i) =>
    new {
        Key = string.Format("{0,2}", i + 1),
        Value =  m,
    });
```

With databinding:

```
ddl.DataSource = months;
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl.DataBind();
```