# Convert a string containing monthName to Int of MonthDigit

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have a string which has short month name in it.\

```
string month = "Jun";
```

I need to get month in digit from this month name.

Say i do this:

```
int monthInDigit = getMonth(month);

monthInDigit <-- 6
```

How can i achieve this. If you cant get my question pleases comment i will explain it proprly.

Thanxx in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Why `monthInDigit` gives `6`?

Comment: @SonerGönül, I would assume because June is the 6th month in the year.

Comment: @Arran Oh, that's the meaning of monthInDigit.. Clever :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a month name (string) to an integer for comparison in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c)

Comment: Sorry but i didnt found this duplicate. Thanx for helping all of you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int monthInDigit = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
```

Comment: Why did u passed null as the last parameter

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: That's not true. If `DateTime.ParseExact` works depends on OP's current culture. If you pass `null` as third parameter you use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. That's why i have used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in my answer.  Not every language abbreviates `June` with `Jun`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanxxx for the extra info and correcting the null paramter information.

Answer (score 9):

You can parse it to a `DateTime` first:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Jun", "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int month = dt.Month;
if(month < 6)
{  
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: u again ..wooow awesome :))

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi: Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` if you want it to work in any culture.

Comment: What if it's June or September? What should the `MMM` be replaced with? Thanks.

Comment: @Si8: if it's not the abbreviated month name but the full name use `MMMM`

Comment: For day that can have `1` or `15` I tried using "dd" but it fails for the `1`.

Comment: What should I use for the day? Thank you.

Comment: @Si8: if `1` is possible then use `d` instead of `dd`. This reading is for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It was failing for me. I had to end up using `PadLeft` to add leading 0 before it worked. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

another way :

```
string [] arr= {jun, fab,...}; 

public int getMonth(string month){

for(int i = 0 ; i< arr.length ; i++){
   if(string[i].Contains(month) || month.Contains(arr[i]))
   return i+1;
   }

return -1;// if month is invalid , return -1
}
```

Comment: This one is totally inefficient dude.