# Calculate month's days based on Year & Month selected

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to get days number based on Year (Years are numbers) & Month (are text) selected from combo box.

Year Combo box name: cmbYear
Month Combo box name: cmbMonth

**Code trigger event:**

```
    private void cmbMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbYear.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
                {
                    var a = cmbDay;
                        a.Enabled = true;
                        a.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                }

                cmbMonth.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                MethodLibrary.Fill_cmbDay(cmbYear,cmbMonth, cmbDay);
```

**Method:**

```
static class MethodLibrary //Method does not return something
{
    public static void Fill_cmbDay(ComboBox strYear, ComboBox strMonth, ComboBox  cmbTarget) //Void used does not return something
    {
        //Find how many days month has based on selected year & month. Convert month name to month number.
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(strYear.SelectedItem), Convert.ToInt32(strMonth.SelectedItem));

        //Clear Combo box
        cmbTarget.Items.Clear();

        //Loop from 1 to number of days & add items to combo box
        for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
        {
            cmbTarget.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserForm:**

[image]

**Error on line:**

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(strYear.SelectedItem), Convert.ToInt32(strMonth.SelectedItem));
```

I believe that error occurs during the conversion of strMonth.SelectedItem to int32.

An help will appreciate.

[image]

Comment: `int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(strYear.SelectedItem), strMonth.SelectedIndex + 1);` Since `"January"` is not a valid *integer* value

Comment: Have you checked the input string when you debugged this error? What is the input string?

Comment: you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220249/convert-a-string-containing-monthname-to-int-of-monthdigit) how to convert month name to month digit

Answer (score 1):

The very reason of the exception is that your try to convert `"January"` string into *integer* value. Try

```
 int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(
   Convert.ToInt32(strYear.SelectedItem), // "2019" can be converted into 2019
   strMonth.SelectedIndex + 1);           // "January" can't; let's take Index then
```

Comment: thanks for your respond. i make to convert month name to int using **int monthInDigit = DateTime.ParseExact(cmbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;**

Comment: @Error 1004: Your are quite right, it's a correct conversion (a bit long, IMHO)

Comment: i post my answer. If you have time to go through and if you can propose correction i ll glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

What i have manage and it works for me:

**Code trigger:**

```
    private void cmbMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbYear.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
                {
                    var a = cmbDay;
                        a.Enabled = true;
                        a.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                }

                cmbMonth.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                int monthInDigit = DateTime.ParseExact(cmbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
                MethodLibrary.Fill_cmbDay(cmbYear, monthInDigit, cmbDay);
        }
    }
```

**Method:**

```
static class MethodLibrary //Method does not return something
{
    public static void Fill_cmbDay(ComboBox strYear, int Month, ComboBox  cmbTarget) //Void used does not return something
    {
        //Find how many days month has based on selected year & month. Convert month name to month number.
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(strYear.SelectedItem),Month);

    //Clear Combo box
    cmbTarget.Items.Clear();

        //Loop from 1 to number of days & add items to combo box
        for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
        {
            cmbTarget.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather *not* extract a `MethodLibrary` *class*: since it tied too tight with `Combobox`s which are on the form (since `Fill_cmbDay` is `public` I can call it as `Fill_cmbDay(cmbTarget, 47, strYear)`)

Comment: When we want to add a *range* let's add a range, something like this `cmbTarget.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, days))`

Comment: If you provide `CultureInfo` *explicitly* `DateTime.ParseExact(cmbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` be sure that you use the same culture when filling in `cmbMonth` combobox

Comment: Side note: (form design) - what is the desired behaviour if I click on maximize button on the "Registration Form". Is it *empty* and *gray* form with some controls in upper left corner? Often do we *remove* maximize and minimize buttons on dialog forms.

Comment: For cmbMonth values,  i import months names in the form load. for the maximization i have not done anything yet.

Comment: Additionally, i try to add a range using the suggested method and i receive an error  **Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'object[]'**

Comment: Add `ToArray()`: `Enumerable.Range(1, days).ToArray()`

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'object[]' another error occurred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191080/discussion-between-error-1004-and-dmitry-bychenko).