# C# transform string to date yyyy-MMM

Tags: c#, string, date

I need transform this **input** string `june 2014` in `2014-06` **output date** and I tried this solution:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(Input.ToString(), "MMM yyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

Response.Write(dt.ToString("yyyy MMM"));
```

But in output I have `0001 jan` , why?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Refer `James Curran's` answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason why it outputs `0001 jan` is because the parse fails, and the function is designed to return `DateTime.Min` if the parse fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your date formatting strings are wrong in couple of places. Try something like this:

```
string Input = "june 2014";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(Input.ToString(), "MMMM yyyy",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM"));
```

Comment: You're not going to check if the `TryParse` was successful before trying to use `dt` as a date object?

Comment: ErikE, I just took OP's example and fixed formatting strings. But you are right, checking would be recommended in case input quality is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 7):

Your format string should be "MMMM yyyy" for input in the format "june 2014", and "yyyy-MM" for output in the format "2014-06":

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
bool parseResult = DateTime.TryParseExact(Input.ToString(), "MMMM yyyy", 
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

if(parseResult)
{
 Response.Write(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM"));
}
else
{
 //Error message about parse fail perhaps?
}
```

- "MMM" is for the 3 letter version such as Jun or Sep.
- "MMMM" is for the full month name such as June or September
- "MM" is for the numeric representation such as 06 or 09.

Comment: You're not going to check if the `TryParse` was successful before trying to use `dt` as a date object?

Comment: Good point. I will include this in my post, but I think OP needs to tell us what would be the default to be written. An error message possibly?