# How to get short month name from full month name?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to get the short month name for the full month name.

For example,

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
this returns - "agosto"

DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
this returns - "ago."
```

This two codes works only to get the current month. I need to get the short month name for all the months.

If I give `"agosto"`, it should return `"ago."`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Loop over the months?

Comment: "This two codes works only to get the current month. I need to get the short month name for all the months." - so some sort of looping construct would seem appropriate...

Comment: and fill an hashmap like structure (Dictionary IIRC)

Comment: Its probably much easier to just create a dictionary or class, that has both parts and will return your desired result, it will only have 12 entries so shouldn't be too laborious

Comment: `If I give "agosto", it should return "ago.". How could I achieve this?` I think the OP wants a function to parse the month's full name into the abbreviation.

Comment: What is the real problem ? You know how to get the abbreviated month name of a given datetime?! So the only problem is that you don't know how to get the other months. But _what_ months do you need at all?

Answer (score 11):

An alternative to [Soner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%c3%b6n%c3%bcl)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420216/215380) that doesn't use a loop:

```
public static string GetAbbreviatedFromFullName(string fullname)
{
    DateTime month;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(
            fullname,
            "MMMM",
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out month)
        ? month.ToString("MMM")
        : null;
}
```

Comment: `+1`, Yeap this seems better than mine.

Comment: @SonerGönül Maybe between us we'll get as many upvotes as the totally wrong answers...

Answer (score 4):

If you can get the month number, this way is pretty easy to get the abbreviated name or full name.

Abbreviated Month Name:

```
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(DateTime.Today.Month)
```

Full Month Name:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Today.Month)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
var dateTimeInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(culture);

foreach (string name in dateTimeInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why this answer upvoted so much. Yes, it gets all abbreviated month names but OP doesn't want this. He/she wants to get abbreviated month name from full month name of his `CurrentCulture`. I don't understand why you used `en-US` culture either.

Comment: Sorry, if your answer dint get any upvotes.:P .. Actually my answer was just an example. I used US english as a culture. OP can try same approach for CurrentCulture.

Comment: Getting upvote is not the point. The point is; try to giving the right answer. This one doesn't even answer the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

> If I give "agosto", it should return "ago."

Then you can use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx) like;

```
public static string GetAbbreviatedFromFullName(string fullname)
{
    string[] names = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;
    foreach (var item in names)
    {
        if (item == fullname)
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(item, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                                 .ToString("MMM");
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

And then can call it like `GetAbbreviatedFromFullName("agosto")`;

Comment: I don't understand reason of `foreach` and comparison, when you have the full name in parameter. Just use it ...

Comment: @Xaruth I think this is more understandable for OP to how to get these values. If you look for a cleaner/better solution, check [Rawling's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25424933/447156) as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass a function the Month's full name, and get the month's short name?

**This method assumes the MonthLongName passed is a valid month name in the current culture.**
If it is not, it will throw an exception.  If that will ever be a possibility, do some validation.

```
public String GetMonthShortName(String MonthLongName)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(MonthLongName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Some code borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258828/3033053)

Comment: This throws exception if `MonthLongName` is not a valid full month name of his `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: Indeed it will.  I'll update my answer to include that tidbit.

Comment: add a `try catch` and it will be perfect.

Comment: I intentionally left the try/catch out for this example because there will need to be validation done somewhere regardless of whether it's inside this function or not. Even if we returned a `String.Empty` in the catch, the OP would need to handle that in his code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all month names you could use something as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("MMM"));
}
```

Comment: This has the drawback, that the result changes it's order depending of the current month. Create a variable which is set to january like this:        var test = new DateTime(2014,1,1)

Comment: Hi Christian, agreed but it depends on the user's use case. If s/he needs to populate a dropdown list to select a month then such an approach would work well. i.e. showing the current month as the first option.

Comment: So, this gets all abbreviated names starts from now. Then what? What is the point? Doesn't answer to question at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
var dateUtil = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
return dateUtil.AbbreviatedMonthNames[DateTime.Now.Month -1];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

`CultureInfo` already has arrays representing both full and abbreviated month names:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[
    Array.FindIndex( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames,
                     t => t.Equals("agosto", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I would like to add my solution (based on @Rawling's answer)for completeness.

Since I needed the conversion in XAML I wrote the following converter.

As I didn't want to add months and days to the resources, the conversion goes from Invariant long (which I have in the "Tag" of the XAML element) to the short Current culture (needed in the "Content") and thus saves extra translations

I also created a converter for the weekdays along the same lines.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Rittal.RiZone.GUI.ValueConverters
{
    public class LongToShortMonthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Long month name from InvariantCulture</param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns>Short text representation of the month in CurrentCulture; null in case no match was found</returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        DateTime month;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(
            value.ToString(),
            "MMMM",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out month)
            ? month.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            : null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Short month name from CurrentCulture</param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns>Long text representation of the month in InvariantCulture; null in case no match was found</returns>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        DateTime month;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(
            value.ToString(),
            "MMM",
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out month)
            ? month.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            : null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
this returns - "agosto";

DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
this returns - "ago.";

Comment: This seems wrong? It will return _current date_ in a format containing days, month and years, and not the short month for _all months_

Answer (score -1):

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
DateTimeFormatInfo abrv = ci.DateTimeFormat;

DateTime dat = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < abrv.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(dat.Year); ctr++) {
     Response.Write(dat.AddMonths(ctr).ToString("MMM", abrv) + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for showing only the code. What I understand is you want to get from long month name to short in every month of the year. So, I gave an example about adding one constant date in "Dat" variable. And then, make "for loop". Please check the code, that I edited.