# Convert month string to int format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following string "Dec".

How can I convert this string to the month number 12?

I tried this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Dec", "MMMM", null).Month
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `ParseExact` method. i.e,

```
string month = "Dec";
int MonthDigit = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use "MMM":

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Dec", "MMM", null).Month
```

also best use a specific culture, so its consisten with the input:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Dec", "MMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")).Month
```

The long version MMMM refers to a full month name as originaly posted here [How to parse a month name (string) to an integer for comparison in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c)