# Library for translating months into integers C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to turn a month name string into an integer. From my form I am getting a string value for the month, "march" or "april". I was wondering if there was a way of using a library in order to get a number from 1 to 12 as a representative of the months value something like this:

```
int monthInDigit = DateTime.ParseExact("march", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
```

this code gives me this error [image]

If not, the other solution I had in mind was for my form to save a integer  value instead of the string name which seems to be the easiest solution at the moment. Still I would like to know what you think and if there is a way of doing this.

Comment: Minus one for not researching this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c

Comment: That does not work I have tried multiple times you will have to create a library manually and thats what I want to avoid. @roryap

Comment: you're an `M` short in your code. should be `"MMMM"` - then it will work

Comment: The whole library for one little function ?!

Comment: @Disappointed There are many ways to do this I want to find out whats the best most efficient way. Manually writing libraries when they exist is not  the best answer.

Comment: Did you take a look at the suggestion to use a `Dictionary<string, int>`?  There's no need to create a library for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked here. Can you paste an example of the string in `creditCard.ExpirationMonth`?  And aren't CC expirations in the format MM/YY ?

Comment: Have you tried "March"?  Month names are capitalized in the Engish language which is what I'm assuming your currentCulture is.

Comment: Here's a link to the valid names of months: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN [DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), "march" is not valid, it has to be capitalized.

> A one-dimensional array of type String containing the culture-specific full names of the months. In a 12-month calendar, the 13th element of the array is an empty string. **The array for InvariantInfo contains "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", and ""**. [emphasis  mine]

In powershell, you can get this list using:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
```